# Ошибка ImportError: cannot import name 'Ui_time' from 'time' (unknown location)

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, qt-designer

получаю эту ошибку когда запускаю код. До этого всё работало, теперь нет.

```
# объяснения сокращений
#_ - конец
# кнп - кнопка
# подкл - подключение
# го - главное окно
#_
# Импорт модулей
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
from time import Ui_time
from oneicran import Ui_oneicran
from hictori import Ui_hictori
from speed import Ui_speed
# Создание главного окна (го)
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
oneicran = QtWidgets.QDialog()
ui = Ui_oneicran()
ui.setupUi(oneicran)
oneicran.show()
#_
# история (кнп4)
def hictorif():
    # Возвращение к го (кнп "назад")
    def beak():
        hictori.close()
        oneicran.show()
    #_
    # кнп очищения истории
    def icranhcist():
        path = "C:\\Users\\Егор\\Desktop\\калькулятор скорости\\дополнительно\\hictorifile.txt"
        file=open(path, encoding="utf-8", mode="w")
        file.write("")
        file.close()
        file=open(path, encoding="utf-8", mode="r")
        ui.textBrowser.setText(str(file.read()))
    #_
    # Подключение окна истории
    global hictori
    hictori = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_hictori()
    ui.setupUi(hictori)
    hictori.show()
    oneicran.close()
    #_
    # Чтение файла
    path = "C:\\Users\\Егор\\Desktop\\калькулятор скорости\\дополнительно\\hictorifile.txt"
    file=open(path, encoding="utf-8", mode="r")
    ui.textBrowser.setText(str(file.read()))
    #_
    # кнп очищения истории
    ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda:icranhcist())
    #_
    # кнп"назад"
    ui.commandLinkButton.clicked.connect(lambda:beak())
    #_
    # закрытие файла 
    file.close()
#_
#скорость (кнп1)
def speedf():
    # Возвращение к го (кнп"назад")
    def beak():
        speed.close()
        oneicran.show()
    #_
    #_Подключение окна скорость
    global speed
    speed = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_speed()
    ui.setupUi(speed)
    speed.show()
    oneicran.close()
    #_
    # функция вычисления скорости
    def do():
        rastoine=ui.lineEdit.text()
        team=ui.lineEdit_2.text()
        rastoinezn=ui.comboBox_8.currentText()
        teamzn=ui.comboBox_7.currentText()
        try:
            speedzn=rastoinezn+"/"+teamzn
            speed=str(int(rastoine)/int(team))
            ui.label_3.setText(speedzn)
            ui.pushButton.setText(speed)
            
        except:
            ui.pushButton.setText("Error")
            ui.label_3.setText("")
        if rastoinezn == "" or rastoine == "" or teamzn == "" or team == "":
            ui.label_3.setText("")
            ui.pushButton.setText("Введите\nвсе\nзначения")
        else:
            path = "C:\\Users\\Егор\\Desktop\\калькулятор скорости\\дополнительно\\hictorifile.txt"
            file=open(path, encoding="utf-8", mode="a")
            file.write("Вычисление скорости\n")
            file.write(str(speed+speedzn+"   "+team+teamzn+"   "+rastoine+rastoinezn+"\n"))
            file.close()
        
    #_
    # подкл к кнп
    ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda:do())
    ui.commandLinkButton.clicked.connect(lambda:beak())
#_
# время (кнп2)

def timef():
    # Возвращение к го (кнп"назад")
    def beak():
        speed.close()
        oneicran.show()
    #_
    #_Подключение окна скорость
    global time
    time = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_time()
    ui.setupUi(time)
    time.show()
    oneicran.close()
    #_
    # функция вычисления времени
    def do():
        rastoine=ui.lineEdit.text()
        speed=ui.lineEdit_2.text()
        speedzn=ui.comboBox.currentText()
        try:
            speedlist=speedzn.split("/")
            timezn=speedlist[1]
            rastoinezn=speedlist[0]
            time=str(int(rastoine)/int(speed))
            ui.label_3.setText(timezn)
            ui.label_4.setText(rastoinezn)
            ui.pushButton.setText(time)
        except:
            ui.pushButton.setText("Error")
            ui.label_3.setText("")
        if rastoinezn == "" or rastoine == "" or teamzn == "" or team == "":
            ui.label_3.setText("")
            ui.label_4.setText("")
            ui.pushButton.setText("Введите\nвсе\nзначения")
        else:
            path = "C:\\Users\\Егор\\Desktop\\калькулятор скорости\\дополнительно\\hictorifile.txt"
            file=open(path, encoding="utf-8", mode="a")
            file.write("Вычисление скорости\n")
            file.write(str(speed+speedzn+"   "+team+teamzn+"   "+rastoine+rastoinezn+"\n"))
            file.close()
        
    #_
    # подкл к кнп
    ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda:do())
    ui.commandLinkButton.clicked.connect(lambda:beak())
# подкл к кнп
ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda:speedf())
ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(lambda:timef())
ui.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(lambda:hictorif())
#_
sys.exit(app.exec_())
#_
```

делаю приложение для вычисления скорости вот код окна которое я делаю

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'time.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.4
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_time(object):
    def setupUi(self, time):
        time.setObjectName("time")
        time.resize(420, 320)
        time.setStyleSheet("background-color:#000000;\n"
"font: 22pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(time)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 50, 113, 111))
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("background-color:#ffffff;\n"
"font: 28pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.lineEdit_2.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 111, 111))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color:#ffffff;\n"
"font: 28pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.commandLinkButton = QtWidgets.QCommandLinkButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.commandLinkButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 0, 185, 41))
        self.commandLinkButton.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.commandLinkButton.setObjectName("commandLinkButton")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 271, 41))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label_2.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 180, 111, 41))
        self.comboBox.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"")
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, "")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 180, 111, 41))
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_3.setText("")
        self.label_3.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label_3.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 180, 111, 41))
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_4.setText("")
        self.label_4.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label_4.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 50, 111, 111))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color:#ffffff;\n"
"font: 20pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        time.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(time)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 420, 41))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        time.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(time)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        time.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(time)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(time)

    def retranslateUi(self, time):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        time.setWindowTitle(_translate("time", "2 экран время"))
        self.commandLinkButton.setText(_translate("time", "Назад"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("time", " время"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("time", "км/ч"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("time", "км/м"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("time", "км/с"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("time", "м/ч"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(5, _translate("time", "м/мин"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(6, _translate("time", "м/сек"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(7, _translate("time", "дм/ч"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(8, _translate("time", "дм/м"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(9, _translate("time", "дм/с"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("time", "нажми\n"
"для\n"
"подщёта"))

В коде могут быть ещё ошибки.
До свидания, заранее спасибо
```

Comment: `time` - модуль для работы со временем в Python. 
См. https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-time.html
Если вы заменете строку `from time import Ui_time` на строку `from my_time import Ui_time`, 
то эта ошибка уйдет и появятся новые ошибки.
Будьте осторожны с выбором имен для модулей, переменных и т.п.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если коротко, то стандартный модуль `time` не содержит метода или поля `Ui_time`

```py
>>> import time
>>> dir(time)
['_STRUCT_TM_ITEMS', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'altzone', 'asctime', 'ctime', 'daylight', 'get_clock_info', 'gmtime', 'localtime', 'mktime', 'monotonic', 'monotonic_ns', 'perf_counter', 'perf_counter_ns', 'process_time', 'process_time_ns', 'sleep', 'strftime', 'strptime', 'struct_time', 'thread_time', 'thread_time_ns', 'time', 'time_ns', 'timezone', 'tzname']
```

Вполне возможно, что был кастомный модуль `time`, но это уже мои догадки и сказать точно я не смогу